# not able to create restaurant.db file in python

Tags: python, sqlite

Below mention is my database configuration file created in python.On executing the code I am not getting restaurant.db file (which is created automatically on execution).Please check my code .thank you

```
import os
import sys
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
Base = declarative_base()
class Restaurant(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'restaurant'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)

class MenuItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'menu_item'
    name = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = Column(String(250))
    price = Column(String(8))
    course = Column(String(250))
    restaurant_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('restaurant.id'))
    restaurant = relationship(Restaurant)
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///restaurantmenu.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: This path "sqlite:///restaurantmenu.db" means, that your database file should be created in the root folder of your filesystem. Do you have write access to it? Or maybe you wanted to write something like "sqlite:///home/user/restaurantmenu.db" ?

Comment: Didnt get you...please explain me again..

Comment: Where do you want to create restaurantmenu.db file? At what folder? If you want create is in the "current" folder, your path should be: "sqlite://{cur_path}/restaurantmenu.db".format(cur_path=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

Comment: My python file is in D drive and I want to create file in D drive.. so what will be the path..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database file should be located on "D" drive, you should set your database file's path to somthing like this: 'sqlite://D:/restaurantmenu.db'

Comment: And one more thing whenever I am trying to import something from database_setup.py (pyton file) to another file it is showing following error.          `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    from database_setup import Base,Restaurant,MenuItem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database_setup'`

Comment: Where does your "database_setup.py" file located relatively to the file, from which you are importing it?